# resume event for Ios not fired in titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to call the resue event it was working in android but not working in Ios. I tried "resume" for Android and "resumed" for Ios. It's not working.

Comment: please show us some code. How do you register the events? For Android you need some custom module the get proper events. For iOS it is `Ti.App.addEventListener("resumed", function() {})`

Comment: i have tried this but it is not working

Comment: i want to call the resume method when i click the back button and navigate to the previous window

Comment: @faizal the `resume` method is only fired when the application returns to the foreground. To call some code when you go back to a previous window you want to use the `focus` event listener on the window if you're pressing the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an "App-wide event listener". As per the documentation you have `resume` and `resumed`

https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-resumed

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("resume", function () {

});
```

Comment: and keep in mind that it is true for iOS but currently not for Android. Proper resume events will be available in 8.0.1 (at least it is the current milestone while writing this). At the moment you'll need a plugin (bencoding.tools) or hyperloop